# Echo Specific Category Description on Magento Frontend

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I want to create a page in the Magento CMS, then echo specific category descriptions on it. What is the code snippet i will need to accomplish this. I am assuming I will need to reference the categories' unique id within the database to echo their description...

thanks for the help!

john

Answer (score 3):

Using PHP:

```
$categoryId = 15;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryId);
if($category->getId()) {
    echo $category->getDescription(); // Should escape this, blocks have $this->escapeHtml()
}
```

I don't know how to do this using magentos email/cms template markup (I don't think its possible) - unless you create a block or widget.

Comment: Thx vague - I assume that works if I create a template page, but how can I accomplish this within a CMS page?

Comment: As I said, you'd probably have to create a block. Something like `{{block type="core/template" template="path_to_your_template.phtml"}}` and you'd place your PHP code in that template